# Django user authentication system for non admin usage (normal user authentication facing customers)?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a forum website and it requires user functionality, however I think the built in User model is only for the admin site, which is for internal use.

I was wondering if there is a Django package for this purpose? Or have I understood the built in package wrong, that it CAN be used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

django's built in User authentication system ***IS*** built for these purposes. Django's admin authentication is nothing different than normal user authentication, it is just a question of permissions.

quotes from docs:

> Django comes with a user authentication system. It handles user
>   accounts, groups, permissions and cookie-based user sessions.

next step for you to read: [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/)

Comment: The built in User model will create and use the table auth_user. If I also use this model for my normal website users, does that mean the normal users will be stored in the same place as my admin user does?

Comment: @JLL yep, it is the same table, but you can extend the djangos user model and stil benefit the built in functions